# Kotlin - setBackground as a hex code programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I currently have a DrawingView which looks like this:

```
        <com.example.drawingapp.DrawingView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawing_view"
        android:background="#80ffffff"
        />
```

Within my code, I am setting the background to nothing earlier on using:

```
drawing_view.setBackgroundResource(0)
```

What I want to be able to do is be able to revert the background back to '#80ffffff' through my code. I have the following which is wrong:

```
drawing_view.setBackgroundResource(ContextCompat.getColor(context, Color.parseColor("#80ffffff")))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
drawing_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80ffffff"))
```